# Find out when a Google document was shared

Tags: google-drive

In Google Docs, is there any way to find out exactly when a document was shared with somebody that I created and shared? This would be useful, at least for me, in finding out exactly when a document was turned in.

Comment: Is this a document that you shared or that was shared among others before you garnered access?

Comment: I shared the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to find out when you shared a document with other people, AND you notified the recipient by email, then you can search Gmail for your message.

In Gmail, search `From:me <title of document>` and it should pull back the email that was sent to the recipient. Body of the message starts with "I've shared an item with you"

If you shared a document with someone but **suppressed** the email notification, then I don't think there is a way to determine when it was sent.

Comment: I can't check my GMail, because I shared it directly from drive

Comment: That's what I mean -- if you chose to alert the recipients with an email that you shared the doc (even from directly in Drive), that email notification will have gone through your Gmail account's Outbox. You can use the search term in the answer in Gmail to see what emails Drive has sent on your behalf to the recipients of the shared document. Hope this clears it up!

Comment: Is there a difference between sent mail and outbox?

Comment: Nope, Sent is the same, and if you use the search operator "From:me:" it will search through all of your sent mail.